# How much hardware resources needs an Eclipse Che host (guest-vm)?

Tags: hardware, requirements, eclipse-che

I'm wondering if I can setup Eclipse Che on my NUC at home?
It has 8gb RAM and quadcore i5 with a 128gb SSH & 500gb HDD. Is that enough?

If anyone has Che setup already, I would appriciate some hardware specs from the host system :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those specs should be fine. I set up che on a virtual machine with a single CPU and 4 gb of ram. The initial setup when creating the first project was slow but once all the docker images etc were downloaded performance was fine.